# Webpack can't import certain npm libraries

Tags: webpack

I am switching my whole setup over from grunt to webpack, I previous included libraries in my grunt file like this.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/counterup

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
      pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
      watch: {
          scripts: {
              files: ['js/*.js'],
              tasks: ['concat:dist1', 'uglify:dist2min']
          },
      },
      concat: {
          options: {
              separator: '\n',
              sourceMap: true
          },
          dist1: { 
              src: [
                  'node_modules/counterup/jquery.counterup.js',
              ],
              dest: 'dist/dist.js'
          },
      },
      uglify: {
          dist2min: {
              options: {
                  mangle: false,
                  drop_console: false
              },
              files: {
                  'dist/bundle.min.js': ['dist/bundle.js']
              }
          }
      },
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch', 'concat:dist1', 'concat:dist2', 'uglify:dist2min', 'cssmin:dist3min']);

};
```

This worked fine I just included the code in my document and could work with it.

I am new to webpack and I am trying the following with an import statement.

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'counterup'; 

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.counter').counterUp({
    delay: 10,
    time: 1000
});

});
```

I get

> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

I have watched a few different tutorials and can't figure out what I am doing wrong I have also tried a few different countup libraries all with the same results.

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what's wrong, but the `countUp` jQuery plugin is too old, and was not updated for so long.
You can use [countUp.js](https://github.com/inorganik/CountUp.js) instead. 
Here is the working example of `countUp.js` with `Webpack 4`.
**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CleanPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: {
    app: './src/index.js',
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].[hash].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanPlugin(['./dist']),
    new HtmlPlugin({
      title: 'test',
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
    }),
  ],
};
```

**src/index.js**

```
import CountUp from 'countup.js';
$('body').html('<span id="counter">1,234,567.00</span>');
var numAnim = new CountUp('counter', 24.02, 99.99);
if (!numAnim.error) {
  numAnim.start();
} else {
  console.error(numAnim.error);
}
```

Comment: you are indeed correct the other countUp works just curious how you would handle an out of date library with Webpack? with grunt you just include the file url does Webpack have a similar fallback?

Comment: Outdated libs do not support `import` statement so if you want to use it, you must manual modify its source code. I haven't use grunt so i'm not sure how its handle outdated lib.